# Can not run build react include ckeditor5

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, vite, ckeditor5

I have a React use `ckeditor5`.
In dev time, every thing is good.

But I can not `run build`

This is `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^5.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "ckeditor5-custom-build": "file:ckeditor5",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.37.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "file": "^0.2.2",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.59.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1"
  }
}
```

The errors I get are in `ckeditor`:

[image]

I try to `npm run build --fix` like log suggest:

[image]

but it not work.

How can I fix that?